# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition freezing the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am building a phonegap application and I have one input element like this:

`<input type="text" id="currLocation"></input>`

And I have a Javascript code like this in bottom of the page:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSucc, onFail,{timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
 }
```

To get the current location of a user. This code works fine, but the only problem I am facing is page freezes until `getCurrentPosition()` completes load(success or failure) and entire page displays as white. What I want is at-least DOM elements should display and this `getCurrentPosition()` should execute in background so UI won't freeze. How do I achieve this? I tried doing like this by calling those without functions in full bottom of the page:

`<script>
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSucc, onFail,{timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
<script>`

But I get below error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getCurrentPosition' on 'Geolocation': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function

Can anyone please guide me in this?

Comment: Downvoter. Please leave a comment so I can improve the question

Comment: can you show the onSucc method??

Comment: In which platform do you find that problem?

Comment: @jcesarmobile in Android

Comment: @AtanuCSE there's nothing much of it, I am just printing console.log that's it.

Comment: AS @AtanuCSE said you should provide the onSucc and onFail, as the problem is there, it seems that for some reason they don't look like a function.

Comment: did you solve it?